# How to use wild card for domCrawler symfony?

Tags: symfony, domcrawler

Is it possible to use wild card to not select some UL LI element like following?

```
<ul>
<li id="i_touch1"></li>
<li id="i_touch2"></li>
<li id="i_touch3"></li>
<li></li> <-- this one
<li></li> <-- this one
</ul>
```

Best regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
$crawler->filterXPath('//ul/li[@id]');
```

### Explaination

It select (at any deep level) all `ul` tags. Inside those tags, it search (and select) for `li` "direct childs" (so not nested ones) that has `id` attribute

Comment: Thank you for your help.